# iOS silver badge

Tags: bug, badges, tag-badges

Why does it say that I have a score of 237 from 400 necessary for the iOS silver badge, when for [my best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727845/find-an-object-in-array/34929289#34929289) alone I have 39 upvotes = 390 score (and it has the `ios` tag)?

Comment: 39 upvotes = 39 score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your **Tags** section where it is showing the following stats:

[image]

237 is your score for that particular tag and As you are saying you have 39 vote means 390 that's your reputations not score. for this answer your score will be 39.